# Add site branding to external site

Tags: 8, theming

Maybe I'm asking the wrong questions on google, but I can't seem to find a solution to what I'm trying to accomplish.

We've created a Drupal 8 site and we need to add the existing header and footer to an external site so that it includes our site branding.

What is the best solution to accomplish this?

I have some initial thoughts, but feel like I'm way off base:

1. Pull the `<header>` and `<footer>` out of the `page.html.twig` template and put them into a separate `header.html.twig` and `footer.html.twig` template. (My base theme is [bootstrap barrio](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_barrio))
2. Create a custom API that exposes the html from the header and footer twig templates. (I'm not sure if this even possible)
3. Using the custom API, expose any paths to custom CSS/JS required for theming.

Then the external website would just call the API, grab the html/css/js and put all the gathered resources on their pages.

Is the above on the right track or am I completely wrong? If I am on the right track, how would I accomplish #2?

Comment: Speaking of my own experience and my own mistakes, this is wrong by concept. Don't do it at all, this is doomed to fail on everything but the simplest cases. If you intentionally want to make your own life harder, you could look how Twig Tweak renders single regions: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak/blob/8.x-2.x/src/TwigExtension.php#L166

Comment: @Hudri not doing it is not an option, but I am open to new ideas/concepts.  How do you propose including site branding from a single site on multiple other websites?

Answer (score 0):

I think creating a service REST API to be consumed by the client sites is the cleanest solution.

This has been implemented in Drupal 7 with [sharedblocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/sharedblocks) but there no Drupal 8 port at this time.

Studying this module would give you a solid foundation on how to accomplish your task in Drupal 8.

Based on the same concept there is also [distributed_blocks](https://www.drupal.org/project/distributed_blocks) module but again does not seem to have a Drupal 8 port.